# Non-static method JUserHelper::getProfile() should not be called statically

Tags: joomla-2.5

I was refactoring some code in an older component and I came across this warning:

```
Strict standards: Non-static method JUserHelper::getProfile() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

$userProfile = JUserHelper::getProfile($userId);

While I do understand the technical nature of the warning, as `getProfile` is not declared `static`, `JUserHelper` is abstract, so it cannot be instantiated.

Curiously all other methods in the class are define as `static`. Looks like a bug in 2.5 to me as in 3.x the signature is different.

So what is the proper way to get the profile?

Comment: I try this with Joomla 3.3.0 and have no problems so far with strict standarts...

Comment: Just in 2.5 is it defined like this.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to use `JUserHelper::getProfile()`, or would you be able to get by with `JFactory::getUser()` instead?

Comment: I need to read values from the user profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug.

This was fixed during J3 development as part of a platform update on 13-Jul-2012 c7c372.

The plaform change was made on 3-Jul-2012 99b6ac PR1341 after initially raising CMS tracker item 28633.

Credit to @valentin for raising bug 33717 and supplying a patch against J2.5.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is most probably a bug in the 2.5 - version. The getProfile()-function in JUserHelper is not used anywhere in the joomla 2.5-distribution, so the bug could go unattended, I guess. To use it as it is declared now you would have to subclass the JUserHelper - class, which really makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug , missing static 
http://prntscr.com/3hl3t1

with static in place print

```
$userProfile = JUserHelper::getProfile(42);
print_r( $userProfile );
```

returns

http://prntscr.com/3hl3x7

for time being you can copy the function over and use it like this

```
function MygetProfile($userId = 0)
{
    if ($userId == 0)
    {
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();
        $userId = $user->id;
    }

    // Get the dispatcher and load the user's plugins.
    $dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
    JPluginHelper::importPlugin('user');

    $data = new JObject;
    $data->id = $userId;

    // Trigger the data preparation event.
    $dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepareData', array('com_users.profile', &$data));

    return $data;
}
$userProfile = MygetProfile(42);
print_r( $userProfile );
```